# R - Identifying the rest of a partial string match or finding partial duplicates within a column

Tags: r, regex

I would like to produce the "Duplicate" column based on "Sample". 003 is a sample ID and 003r is a replicate of the same sample.
The replicated sample names in the "Sample" column are identical in their first 3 characters.

```
Sample <- c("001","002","003","003r","004","005","005r")
Value <- c(2,5,4,4,5,6,7)
Duplicate <- c(F,F,T,T,F,T,T)
df <- data.frame(Sample,Value,Duplicate)
df

  Sample Value Duplicate
1    001     2     FALSE
2    002     5     FALSE
3    003     4      TRUE
4   003r     4      TRUE
5    004     5     FALSE
6    005     6      TRUE
7   005r     7      TRUE
```

I was trying with `ifelse` and `grep` but couldn't combine them in the way that gave me the wanted result, and I'm stuck at this point.
I would appreciate the help, thanks.

Comment: Can you say a little more about the data: Is it always the first 3 characters you are interested in? Are the parts you want to check for duplication always numbers and the variation characters?

Comment: You could try `stringdist::stringdistmatrix(df$Sample)` but it is not clear why `003r` and `003` are dupes but not `001` and `002`- both pairs have one character distance. If all you are looking for is to match the first 3 characters, you could simple do `duplicated(substring(df$Sample, 1, 3)) | duplicated(substring(df$Sample, 1, 3), fromLast = TRUE)` which gives your desired output.

Comment: @DavidArenburg thanks a lot, this is what I was looking for, and after a while I also understood how it works.

Answer (score 0):

@David Arenburg is right, you need to first formally define what you mean by 'partially matching' names. Assuming partially matching is defined by perfect match (being identical) between position 1 (start) and 3 (stop) of your substring in sample, we can create a new column holding this substring:

```
df$sample_substr <- substr(df$Sample,start = 1,stop = 3)
```

... and then simply count the occurrences (frequencies) of each sample_substr. I suggest using the 'plyr' package for that (it is very quick):

```
library(plyr)
# group by 'sample_substr' and count the number of occurrences
df <- ddply(df, .(sample_substr), mutate, frequency=length(sample_substr))
# if frequency is 1, it is unique, i.e. not a duplicate. If frequency is > 1, it is not unique, i.e. a duplicate.
df$Dup <- ifelse(df$frequency==1, FALSE, TRUE)
# test if our definition of Dup holds the same value as yours in Duplicate
df$Dup==df$Duplicate
```